# How to make a Emoticon Keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, emoticons

I am trying to develop a emoticon keyboard for Android. I would like for the user to be able to purchase the app and install the emoticons to use with their keyboard for text and social networking my emoticons are graphics would I have to create a softkeyboard? how can I go about making this app any source codes advice would be appreciated I am new to app development its nothing like web..PLEASE HELP!!

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16768930/implementations-of-emoji-emoticon-view-keyboard-layouts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to develop a emoticon keyboard for Android

Please bear in mind that most people do not speak exclusively in emoticons. Either you will need to create a full natural-language soft keyboard that *also* has emoticons, or users will have to flip back and forth between their regular soft keyboard and yours. The latter seems unlikely to be popular.

> would I have to create a softkeyboard?

You are asking to create a soft keyboard.

> how can I go about making this app

There is a `SoftKeyboard` sample app in your SDK that you can use as a starting point. Beyond that, search for tutorials on how to create an [`InputMethodService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/InputMethodService.html).

Comment: Thank you so much!!!I have been recking my brain my head is killing me.. This is so new to me I have become familiar with main.xml I have used a keyboard code I found on the developer site   but its not showing the actual keyboard in main.xml once I start coding in java will it show?

Comment: @evc: I have never written a soft keyboard, so I do not know what it looks like when working in Eclipse.

Comment: oh ok well I am going to try my luck with this Im am really nervous about coding in java, some of it just doesnt make any sense...thank you again you have no idea how much you have helped me!!!